# Why would someone use a Memory Mapped File in PRIVATE mode?

Tags: java, memory-management, io, real-time, nio

The documentation does not say much besides:

> Private: Changes made to the resulting buffer will not be propagated
>   to the file and will not be visible to other programs that have mapped
>   the same file; instead, they will cause private copies of the modified
>   portions of the buffer to be created. (MapMode.PRIVATE)

In what situation is it desirable and what advantages does it have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're running a [genetic-algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm) experiment on a large dataset, you might wish to start eight or more clients -- one per core, two per core, etc. -- to work with the same starting data, make modifications to the data as it performs the computation, and then save only "final results" of the starting seed for the random number generator and the "score" against which the algorithm is being measured.

The intermediate results might not have any value and you wouldn't want any of the clients to ever see intermediate results from other clients nor taint the initial seed data.

Answer (score 1):

> In what situation is it desirable and what advantages does it have?

It is used when you want to make temporary changes to the mapped data that should not be persisted, and should not be visible to other applications that might have mapped the file.

In such a use-case, the application can either explicitly copy the file contents into a `byte[]`, or it can map the file in `PRIVATE` mode

The expectation is that JVM + OS will take care of the data copying in PRIVATE mode in a more efficient way than the Java application code can.  For instance, the JVM + OS might could use the native virtual memory subsystem to copy the data in a mapped VM page the first time that the application tries to update the corresponding region of its buffer.

How `MapMode.PRIVATE` is actually implemented is platform specific.  If you need to know the details, refer to your JVM's source code and the operating system source code.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux systems for example the .text segment of a processes is loaded in PRIVATE mode, in-fact they initially share the memory in Copy On Write mode and if a one of the process try to modify its code only that process will affect and there isn't any propagation to the file system.